# Entity Framework Skip and Take didn't translated to SQL command

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
var allUseresInclude = _userService.Include(r => r.Profession);

var model = allUseresInclude.Select(s => new ViewModel.User
{
    Profession = s.Profession.Name,
    Id = s.Id,
    ProviderUserId = s.ProviderUserId,
    PlatformId = s.PlatformId,
    Email = s.Email,
    Password = s.Password,
    RefreshToken = s.RefreshToken,
    Name = s.Name,
    Surname = s.Surname,
    Fullname = s.Name + " " + s.Surname,
    Gender = s.Gender,
    ProfessionId = s.ProfessionId,
    BirthDate = s.BirthDate.ToString(),
    IdentityNumber = s.IdentityNumber,
    Phone = s.Phone,
    IsActive = s.IsActive,
    CreatedDate =  _common.DateTimeToTimeZone(s.CreatedDate),//.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"),
    EmailConfirmed = s.EmailConfirmed
});

var tt = model.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate).Skip(20).Take(30).ToList();
```

Model is a IQueryable variable. First, I am selecting the properties for my ViewModel then I try to filter my IQueryable. Query execution takes a while and I see correct results in UI, but in SQL the generated query doesn't have offset or limit

```
    SELECT [r].[CreatedDate], [r.Profession].[Name] AS [Profession], [r].[Id], [r].[ProviderUserId], [r].[PlatformId], [r].[Email], [r].[Password], [r].[RefreshToken], [r].[Name], [r].[Surname], ([r].[Name] + N' ') + [r].[Surname] AS [Fullname], [r].[Gender], [r].[ProfessionId], CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [r].[BirthDate]) AS [BirthDate], [r].[IdentityNumber], [r].[Phone], [r].[IsActive], [r].[EmailConfirmed]
FROM [User] AS [r]
LEFT JOIN [Profession] AS [r.Profession] ON [r].[ProfessionId] = [r.Profession].[Id]
```

When I fire this query, it returns all the tables so I guess my skip and take doesn't work as expected. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this full code var tt = model.OrderByDescending? Is there anything between model and OrderByDescending?

Comment: It doesn't look like `OrderByDescending` was added either. You *say* that `model` is an IQueryable, can you show us the actual code that initializes model, declares it, etc.?

Comment: Are you sure that the `SQL` is generated on hitting the line of code where you are calling `Skip` and `Take`? Or it is generated before that, when you are initializing the `model`? You maybe be doing something that might just execute the `SQL` before hand.

Comment: No, i checked that, query fires when i call ToList()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the reasons for this is using .ToList() or .Select() to early. So, that means you should check if your query really producing IQueryable.

```
var model = allUseresInclude.Select(s => new ViewModel.User
{
    Profession = s.Profession.Name,
    Id = s.Id,
    ProviderUserId = s.ProviderUserId,
    PlatformId = s.PlatformId,
    Email = s.Email,
    Password = s.Password,
    RefreshToken = s.RefreshToken,
    Name = s.Name,
    Surname = s.Surname,
    Fullname = s.Name + " " + s.Surname,
    Gender = s.Gender,
    ProfessionId = s.ProfessionId,
    BirthDate = s.BirthDate.ToString(),
    IdentityNumber = s.IdentityNumber,
    Phone = s.Phone,
    IsActive = s.IsActive,
    CreatedDate =  _common.DateTimeToTimeZone(s.CreatedDate),//.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"),
    EmailConfirmed = s.EmailConfirmed
});
```

In your code pay attention to `_common.DateTimeToTimeZone` this will force Entity Framework to be executed in the memory otherwise this cannot be executed and translated to the SQL query.

If this part is executed in the application memory that means Skip and Take are executed after that in the memory as well.

You should try with some solution like this one:

```
var model = allUseresInclude.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate).Skip(20).Take(30).Select(s => new ViewModel.User
{
    Profession = s.Profession.Name,
    Id = s.Id,
    ProviderUserId = s.ProviderUserId,
    PlatformId = s.PlatformId,
    Email = s.Email,
    Password = s.Password,
    RefreshToken = s.RefreshToken,
    Name = s.Name,
    Surname = s.Surname,
    Fullname = s.Name + " " + s.Surname,
    Gender = s.Gender,
    ProfessionId = s.ProfessionId,
    BirthDate = s.BirthDate.ToString(),
    IdentityNumber = s.IdentityNumber,
    Phone = s.Phone,
    IsActive = s.IsActive,
    CreatedDate =  _common.DateTimeToTimeZone(s.CreatedDate),//.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"),
    EmailConfirmed = s.EmailConfirmed
}).ToList();
```

Comment: model is still IQueryable after that part.

Comment: It is not, there is .ToList() at the end. Pay attention to command order in Lambda Expression.

Comment: My comment was before your edit, after _common.DateTimeToTimeZone it was still an iqueryable. I tried your solution and now sql generates offset but whats the difference, whats wrong with my code

Comment: Problem is that the Entity Framework in your code loaded all data in the application memory and then in the memory filtered and skip data. That is the reason why you first need to put OrderBy, Skip and Take before Select because in the select you have some code that cannot be transleted in the SQL.

Comment: when i debug it was still an iqueryable that confused me. So whenever i apply orderby,skip or take, i apply it before select, because linq cannot translate code like "Profession = s.Profession.Name" for example am i right ?

Comment: Actually, there is no specific rule where to put OrderBy, in this case, Take and Skip requires OrderBy before, in most of the cases OrderBy is set after Select, but if you are creating a custom model then is set before. As I said it depends, there are no rules except in these cases where you are forced to use somewhere.